# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. File.Create method

Tags: c#

This is a body of method:

```
// Get files from directory base on search pattern
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, searchOption);

List<string> contents = ReadMetadataFile(path, out metaDataFilePath);

if (contents == null || contents.Count == 0)
   listFiles = ProcessIfMetadataIsNull(files, metaDataFilePath);
```

In ProcessIfMetadataIsNull method, I call a method to write data:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(metaDataFilePath, isAppend))
{
   foreach (var item in assemblyFiles)
   {
       sw.WriteLine(item.GetStringToWrite());
   }
}
```

In ReadMetadataFile method:

```
// Get meta data file path
metaDataFilePath = MetaDataFilePath(directory);

// Read meta data content
List<string> contents = ReadContentFile(metaDataFilePath);

return contents;
```

In MetaDataFilePath method:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
   Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

string metaDataFilePath = Path.Combine(path, Metadata);
if (!File.Exists(path))
   File.Create(path);`

return metaDataFilePath;
```

In the first time, metadata file was not create, I uploaded a file and it was created, exception was thrown. After that, I removed all file in directory which store metadata file. Then I uploaded again, the exception  was thrown. If I keep metadata file, exception is gone. 
So, the problem come from the File.Create method. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What is the point of creating an empty file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is unhelpful because the most frequent cause of this error that most *programmers* experience is when their *own* process is the cause of the blockage, as it is here. So the error message blaming "another process" is incorrect.

[`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); an object that, in common with other streams, is [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - you should dispose of it when you no longer need it. This may be as simple as:

```
string metaDataFilePath = Path.Combine(path, Metadata);
if (!File.Exists(path))
   File.Create(path).Dispose();
```

Comment: if I use using, how do I write it?

Comment: @Tigran - in this case, you'd be creating an empty `using` block though - which to my mind obscures more than it clarifies.

Comment: so it's better to refactor code, in sence of do not allow blind contemporary access. File.Create(..).Dispose(..) does not look very nice either.

Comment: Also, you must include `File.Create` in to `try/catch` block in edge cases.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I use Dispose method and it works. I will mark the answer in 7 minutes :) (it told me like that :D)